# How do I round numbers to the nearest integer from the command line?

Tags: command-line

There is a file I have which look

```
555.92 569.472 582.389 648.078 999.702 1040.75 1386.24 1418.47 1998.26 2182.13 2384.3
```

I would need to round every number like this

```
556 569 582
```

Ideally i don't need to create a tmp file. How to do that ?

Comment: The answers provided are good (and better than what I'm just about to mention), but just for the fun of mentionning it: a possibility is to add "0.5" to each number and keep just the integer part (for ex: drop the decimal part). There are many ways to do that one (and many caveats, especially when you reach the maximum value, which in turns depends on the program and its implementation)

Answer (score 10):

Run the contents of the file through printf function.

```
 $ xargs -a numbers.txt -n1 printf "%1.f "                                   
    556 569 582 648 1000 1041 1386 1418 1998 2182 2384
```

Also ,Ubuntu has nice little program called `numfmt` which allows formating numbers to user defined standards, and human readable.

For example,

```
$ xargs -a numbers.txt -n1 numfmt  --to=si --round=up | xargs echo 
556 570 583 649 1.0K 1.1K 1.4K 1.5K 2.0K 2.2K 2.4K
```

Check [`man numfmt`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/numfmt.1) for more info.

Comment: or even `printf "%1.f " $(cat numbers.txt)`

Answer (score 5):

`bash` can only handle integer arithmetic. Use a more powerful language, e.g. Perl:

```
perl -ane 'printf "%.0f ", $_ for @F' file
```

- `-n` reads the input line by line
- `-a` splits each line on whitespace to the `@F` array
- `%.0f` is a flow format with zero digits after the decimal point

Answer (score 5):

Another python solution (one -liner). Run in a terminal:

```bsh
python3 -c "[print(round(float(n))) for n in open('f').read().split()]"
```

Where `'f'` is the source file with your floats, between single quotes, e.g.:

```bsh
python3 -c "[print(round(float(n))) for n in open('/home/jacob/Bureaublad/test').read().split()]"
```

Output:

```
556
569
582
648
1000
1041
1386
1418
1998
2182
2384
```

#### Another way of output

If you'd like the figures in one row:

```bsh
python3 -c "[print(round(float(n)), end=' ') for n in open('f').read().split()]"
```

(Thanks @Oli!)

Output:

```
556 569 582 648 1000 1041 1386 1418 1998 2182 2384
```

#### Explanation

The command:

```bsh
python3 -c "[print(round(float(n))) for n in open('f').read().split()]"
```

in sections:

```py
open('f').read().split()
```

reads the file `'f'`, splits it into floats (now still as string)

```py
round(float(n))
```

First interprets the *string* `n` as float, *rounds* it to an integer

```py
[print(round(float(n))) for n in open('f').read().split()]
```

finally, generates the print command, to print all rounded floats.

Comment: @HenkLangeveld Thanks a lot for the edit, but I'd like to keep the "one liner" :)

Comment: I'll hold off editing, but you can use Py3k's `print(..., end=' ')` argument instead of needing to do a separate `' '.join(...)`. It would read something like: `for n in open('f').read().split(): print(int(round(float(n))), end=' ')`. Shorter and because you skip list comprehension, it's somewhat easier to follow for Python novices too.

Comment: @Oli *much* shorter, and much nicer to look at :). Thanks!

Comment: @Oli I am not sure..is it a good idea to take the whole file in memory even if it is of much bigger size?

Comment: @heemayl not sure how big a file you are imagining, but on a file, more than a million floats, (written to a file, since printing in the terminal is what takes the time, not *processing* the floats) it is done in a split second. Also, looking at the question, there is only one line, so reading line by line is actually equal to loading the whole file  :)

Comment: @JacobVlijm aye..my question is isn't it better to read the file line by line, use least resource & let the formatting be done at once....please correct me if I'm barking the wrong tree..

Comment: @heemayl It depends on the situation. I have even had situations that reading the whole file was even faster. In the size of the example of the question (or even much bigger files), I'd go for the shorter code however. Only on *really* huge files, the question becomes relevant imo. You might want to change `rstrip()` into simply `strip()` by the way, else the script will break if a line starts with a space for some reason.

Answer (score 4):

Using `python`:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python2
with open('/path/to/file.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        numbers = line.strip().split(' ')
        for num in numbers:
            print int(round(float(num))),
```

- The list `numbers` will contain all the numbers spitted on spaces (`line.rstrip().split(' ')`)
- Then we have used the `round()` function to round the floating point numbers
- As the inputs are stored as srings we need to use the `float()` function to convert them to floats
- The `int()` function will print the number discarding the decimal points i.e. only the integer portion

**Output :**

```
556 569 582 648 1000 1041 1386 1418 1998 2182 2384
```

Answer (score 4):

Where is the `awk` version? `printf` can also be used in `awk`:

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {printf "%0.f ",$i} printf "\n"}'
```

or inplace without a temporary file (Thx [@muru](https://askubuntu.com/users/158442/muru))

```
awk -i inplace '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {printf "%0.f ",$i} printf "\n"}'
```

---

*Example*

```
% cat foo
555.92 569.472 582.389 648.078 999.702 1040.75 1386.24 1418.47 1998.26 2182.13 2384.3

% awk '{
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
    printf "%0.f ",$i
  }
  printf "%s","\n"
}' foo
556 569 582 648 1000 1041 1386 1418 1998 2182 2384
```

Comment: With `-i inplace` for in-place editing, thus avoiding a temporary file like OP wants.

Answer (score 2):

This should work for you:

```
perl -ne '@l=split(/\s+/,$_); foreach(@l){printf("%.0f",$_); print " "}'
```

you can use it like

```
echo "555.92 569.472 582.389" | perl -ne '
  @l=split(/\s+/,$_);
  foreach(@l) {
    printf("%.0f",$_);
    print " "
  }'
```

Comment: Try this: `perl -F'/\s/' -ane 'foreach(@F){printf "%.0f ",$_}' foo`

Answer (score 2):

Using `perl`:

```
perl -ne 'printf("%.0f ", $_) for split' file
```